# C custom malloc function not reading block size

Tags: c, malloc

I try to implement a custom malloc function. I have issues with the size part. Since we can free a variable, the empty space can be reallocated. The custom structure is 32 bits long and contains the size of the data and a bit as a boolean (unsigned int free : 1) that says if the data is free or not.

Here is my malloc function :

```
void *mymalloc(size_t size) {
if (!size) return NULL;
size_t length = align(size + sizeof(struct header));
Header current = availableHeader(size);
if (!(current==sbrk(0))) {
    Header newHeader = sbrk(length);
    if (newHeader == (void*) -1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    newHeader->size = length - sizeof(struct header);
    current = newHeader;

} else if (length + sizeof(size_t) < current->size) {

    split(current, length);
}
current->free = 0;
return current+sizeof(struct header);
}
```

This uses a function called "availableHeader" that will find the first available memory morsel, a new one if no other morsel is free AND has enough size to store the data.

```
Header availableHeader(size_t s) {
Header current = firstHeader();
int isHeader=1;
for (;isHeader && (!current->free || current->size < s); current = current+current->size+sizeof(struct header)){
    printf("%d on %d for %d\n", current->free, current->size, s);//TEST
    if(current>=sbrk(0)){
        isHeader=0;
    }
}
return current;
}
```

And finally, this function uses "firstHeader" which returns the first morsel we created, it creates the first one if it's the first call.

```
static void *firstHeader() {
static Header b = NULL;
if (!b) {
    b = sbrk(align(sizeof(struct header)));
    if (b == (void*) -1) {
        _exit(127);
    }
    b->size = 0;
    b->free = 0;       
}
return b;
}
```

Now, the problem is that "availableHeader" never returns an already-created block. It always results in creating a new one which is a terrible memory management strategy.
By testing (marked //TEST) i saw that my loop in "availableHeader" always sees the current memory block with "0" for both size and free.

It seems like my malloc function never sets a size even though there is this line :

```
newHeader->size = length - sizeof(struct header);
```

But the issue stays : reading the size in "availableHeader" returns 0 even if it has another value.

**EDIT :**
As requested, here's the structure :

```
struct header {
    unsigned int size : 29,
                 zero :  2,
                 free :  1;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that the header structure is correctly created? Can you show declaration?

Comment: I edited to put the structure.

Comment: `static Header b = NULL;` -->> `static Header *b = NULL;` maybe?

Comment: `current+sizeof(struct header);` wrong pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `availableHeader` returns a pointer to the header which can be reused `(free == 1 && size >= s)` your `mymalloc` function hits the `if (!(current==sbrk(0)))` because current is not at the program break. False negate to true and you allocate new memory instead of reusing the old one.

Comment: That may be the solution to another problem. But for now, i am not able to retrieve the size attribute. Since availableHeader cannot read the size of the examined header, it cannot go "correctly" to the next one.

To iterate through the headers, my function should add 32 bits (sizeof header) + X bits where X is the size attribute. But since it cannot retrieve the size, the "current" header is not a header.

Comment: Sure it can not. Check how pointer arithmetic works. Current + 10 does not mean move 10 bytes but 10 times the size of the referenced object. Type it to `(void *)`.

Comment: Thanks. I worked on my code but i was stuck after that, i decided to start over from scratch. But the generic pointer helped a lot ! Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSilon Pointer arithmetic to `(void *)` is not allowed in Standard C. (you use it is probably an extension of the GCC) [sample code](http://ideone.com/a7RtWo)